# What 3rd party Android WebView that can open webpage with TLS v1.2

Tags: android, cordova, ssl, webview

I'm using android webview to open some secure webpage with TLS v1.2 encryption. Little that I know that not all android versions support this encryption. Can anyone suggest any solution with examples or 3rd party library that can solve this problem?
I have googled and found no articles that can help me. The closest one I found is Cordova WebView, but I don't know what it is and how to apply it in my android application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I found the article. Just download the completed project at the bottom of the article, and then follow the tutorial 
[Embed Cordova Webview](http://www.catharinegeek.com/embed-cordova-webview-in-android-native-app/)